# Using Option in functional way to avoid if-else

Tags: scala, scala-option

I have an Option instance, say O,  which contains an instance of a class, say A, and A itself has some Options inside it.

I have to achieve something like this, expressed in pseudo code as:

```
if(A.x exists) {
  if(A.y exists) {
   //extract values from some another Option Z embedded in A
  } else {
   // return Option of some default value
  }
}
```

So I try this:

```
O.filter(some filter condition to have only some specific types of A).filter(!A.x.isEmpty).filter(!A.y.isEmpty).flatMap(_.z.somevalue).orElse(Some("Some default value"))
```

Is this the correct way, OR do I need to use pattern matching at some point?

Edit: Result should be an Option[String].O si an Option[A]. A is a class with fields x,y,z, and all three are Option of String.

Comment: It would be easier to help if you can provide example definitions of those types; also it is not clear what the final result should be.

Comment: Rather use `Option` combinators or pattern matching; e.g `(for { x <- A.x; y <- A.y } yield somethingWith(x, y)).getOrElse(defaultValue)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks like a good use case for **pattern matching**.

For what I understood of your question you want something like this:
*(if not, the code should be easy to adjust)*

```scala
final case class A(x: Option[String], x: Option[String], x: Option[String])

def getData(oa: Option[A]): Option[String] = oa match {
  case Some(A(Some(_), Some(_), z)) => z
  case None => None
  case _ => Some("Default Value")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest expression of this would be

```
A.x.map(x => A.y.fold(default_value)(y => calculation_using_y))
```